# listing files in the directory using grep

Tags: regex, unix, grep

List all the files in `/usr/bin` whose **filenames** contain **lowercase English alphabet
characters** only and also contain the word **file** as a (contiguous) substring.

For example, **file** and **profiles** are such files, but **git-ls-files** is not.

This is the exact question I have and I can only use `grep`, `ls`, `cat` and `wc` for it.

```
ls /usr/bin/ | grep '[^-]*file'
```

This is what I got so far and output is below. I dont know how to display for example just `file` since `* is zero or more occurences`. And no idea how to put lowercase thing in the regex as well..

```
check-binary-files
clean-binary-files
desktop-file-install
desktop-file-validate
ecryptfs-rewrite-file
file
filep
git-cat-file
git-diff-files
git-ls-files
git-merge-file
git-merge-one-file
git-unpack-file
lockfile
nsrfile
pamfile
pcprofiledump
pnmfile
ppufiles
profiles
```

Comment: Why down vote? OP has listed it as homework, have stated the requirements given expected result and shown what he has tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ls /usr/bin/ | grep --regex '^[[:lower:]]*file[[:lower:]]*$'
```

The ^ and $ match the beginning and end of the string, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Using `ls` piped with `grep` is really redundant in that situation. You can use `find`:

```
$> find /usr/bin -regex "/usr/bin/[a-z]*file[a-z]*" -type f -printf "%f\n"
profiles
keditfiletype
inifile
dotlockfile
pamfile
pnmfile
file
konsoleprofile
```

Comment: The question says "I can only use grep ls cat wc," but this is definitely the way to go if those constraints are not present.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -1 /usr/bin | grep '^[a-z]*file[a-z]*$'
```

`ls -1` makes sure the files are listed each in a single line. `^` and `$` are symbols for start and end of line, which is what you were missing (otherwise it can match a substring of the filename)

Answer (score 0):

Use **-P** option, means Perl regular expressions, so finally your command would look like:

```
ls /usr/bin | grep -P '[a-z]file'

insider@gfl ~/test/bin$ ls
123file             desktop-file-install   file          git-diff-files  git-merge-one-file  nsrfile        pnmfile   testlist
check-binary-files  desktop-file-validate  filep         git-ls-files    git-unpack-file     pamfile        ppufiles
clean-binary-files  ecryptfs-rewrite-file  git-cat-file  git-merge-file  lockfile            pcprofiledump  profiles
insider@gfl ~/test/bin$ ls . | grep -P '[a-z]file'
lockfile
nsrfile
pamfile
pcprofiledump
pnmfile
ppufiles
profiles
```